# How to add new items to combobox which is bound to Entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, binding, combobox, row

Design class which is generated by C# :

```
    // 
    // usepurposeComboBox
    // 
    this.usepurposeComboBox.DataSource = this.usepurposeBindingSource;
    this.usepurposeComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    this.usepurposeComboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
    this.usepurposeComboBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(277, 53);
    this.usepurposeComboBox.Name = "usepurposeComboBox";
    this.usepurposeComboBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(218, 21);
    this.usepurposeComboBox.TabIndex = 4;
    this.usepurposeComboBox.ValueMember = "id";
    // 
    // usepurposeBindingSource
    // 
    this.usepurposeBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(mydatabaseEntities.usepurpose);
```

Then I bound the BindingSource (usepurposeBindingSource) to Entities :

```
usepurposeBindingSource.DataSource = mydatabaseEntities.usepurposes;
```

And I can not add a new row to usepurposeComboBox because it's been bound. Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it on my own. I created a new unbound combobox then bind it to a datatable. Not sure if it's the best way but it works for me. Thanks for all of your suggestions. :)

```
private void FillCombobox()
        {
            using (mydatabaseEntities mydatabaseEntities = new mydatabaseEntities())
            {
                List<usepurpose> usepurposes = mydatabaseEntities.usepurposes.ToList();              
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("id");
                dt.Columns.Add("Name");
                dt.Rows.Add(-1, "test row");
                foreach (usepurpose usepurpose in usepurposes)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(usepurpose.id, usepurpose.Name);
                }
                usepurposeComboBox.ValueMember = dt.Columns[0].ColumnName;
                usepurposeComboBox.DisplayMember = dt.Columns[1].ColumnName;
                usepurposeComboBox.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way is to add a new row to your dataTable and then bind your comboBox to it something like this:

Company comps = new Company();

```
        //pupulate dataTable with data
        DataTable DT = comps.getCompaniesList();

        //create a new row
        DataRow DR = DT.NewRow();
        DR["c_ID"] = 0;
        DR["name"] = "Add new Company";
        DR["country"] = "IR";

        //add new row to data table
        DT.Rows.Add(DR);

        //Binding DataTable to cxbxCompany
        cxbxCompany.DataSource = DT;
        cxbxCompany.DisplayMember = "name";
        cxbxCompany.ValueMember = "c_ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to add for example a first item sometimes called "Choose One" as if you want to live data you should just see where the data comes from and add more items to that "table".

`this.usepurposeBindingSource` is an object ... why not adding into it before it binds?

if it's a `List<T>` this will be fine

```
this.usepurposeBindingSource.Insert(0, new T() {
    Name = "Choose one",
    Id = ""
});
```

Then `Bind()` it...

**Remember** to validate as it's a string and will not be the object you want

---

This is working:

```
List<MyObject> usepurposeBindingSource { get; set; }

private void FillUpData()
{
    // Simulating an External Data
    if (usepurposeBindingSource == null || usepurposeBindingSource.Count == 0)
    {
        this.usepurposeBindingSource = new List<MyObject>();
        this.usepurposeBindingSource.Add(new MyObject() { Name = "A", ID = 1 });
        this.usepurposeBindingSource.Add(new MyObject() { Name = "B", ID = 2 });
        this.usepurposeBindingSource.Add(new MyObject() { Name = "C", ID = 3 });
    }
}

private void FillUpCombo()
{
    FillUpData();

    // what you have from design
    // comment out the first line
    //this.usepurposeComboBox.DataSource = this.usepurposeBindingSource;
    this.usepurposeComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
    this.usepurposeComboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
    this.usepurposeComboBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(277, 53);
    this.usepurposeComboBox.Name = "usepurposeComboBox";
    this.usepurposeComboBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(218, 21);
    this.usepurposeComboBox.TabIndex = 4;
    this.usepurposeComboBox.ValueMember = "id";

    // to do in code:

    this.usepurposeBindingSource.Insert(0, new MyObject() { Name = "Choose One", ID = 0 });

    // bind the data source
    this.usepurposeComboBox.DataSource = this.usepurposeBindingSource;

}
```

The trick is to comment out the `DataSource` line and do it in your code, **inserting** one more element into your object that is from your Model

`//this.usepurposeComboBox.DataSource = this.usepurposeBindingSource;`

Comment: It can't be done. An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Comment: why not them add to `this.usepurposeBindingSource` ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this, is to wrap your BindingSource with some kind of "ViewModel". The new class will return a "complete" list of items - both those provided from the original binding source, as well as those "additional" items.

You can then bind the new wrapper to your combobox.

I wrote an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/UnboundItemsComboBox.aspx) about this a while back... It's not my finest work, and it's probably a bit outdated, but it should get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link: http://forums.asp.net/t/1695728.aspx/1?

In asp you can add this to insert an empty line:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="CustomerDropDownList" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="CustomerEntityDataSource" DataTextField="CustomerId"
    DataValueField="CustomerId" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select All Customers" Value="" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Or in code behind:

```
    DropDownList1.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select All Customers", "-1"));
```

Comment: The attribute AppendDataBoundItems seems to be only available for DropDownLists and not Comboxes.